# How do I determine if a vector is unitary?

Tags: vectors

I have a vecor of the form

$$w=\frac{1}{||r-s||}(r-s)$$

How do I determine if its unitary or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by unitary you mean has norm one, then just directly compute:
$$ ||w||=\frac{1}{||r-s||}\cdot||r-s||=1 $$

This is of course assuming $r\neq s$. The homogeneity of the norm allows you to pull out any constant (with an absolute value).

Comment: Oh ok so you just took the norm of the numerator. Makes sense I guess lol